# ES6 promises - can somebody explain this piece of promises code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

Can someone explain how the following piece of code works?

```
var a = () => { 
  return Promise.resolve('aaa'); 
};

var b = () => { 
  return Promise.resolve('bbb'); 
};


a()
  .then(() => { b() })
  .then(console.log);  // logs undefined

a()
  .then(b())
  .then(console.log); // logs aaa

a()
  .then(b)
  .then(console.log); // logs bbb
```

I would like to know the sequence of execution of multiple .then on a single promise and how b() vs b vs promise () => { b() } makes difference in the output.

Comment: `() => { b() }` is a function that doesn’t return anything. This has nothing to do with promises, but with arrow function syntax. And `b()` isn’t a function at all…

Comment: Could you explain why "undefined" is logged in first case and why 'aaa' is logged in the second case?

Comment: `undefined` is a result of a function that doesn’t return anything.

Comment: What do you expected to happen when you pass a *promise* to `.then` in the second example?

Comment: This is more of a question about a misunderstanding of callbacks and anonymous functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Secnario A:** Your first one doesn't return anything from the `.then()` handler (there's no `return` statement inside the `{}` and arrow functions don't use an implicit return when there's `{}`) so the return value from the `.then()` handler is `undefined` and that's what you log.

`.then(() => { b() })` would need to be any of these to work properly:

```
.then(() => { return b() })     // since there are {}, you must have an actual `return`
.then(() => b())                // use implicit return in arrow function
.then(b)                        // just pass function reference directly
```

**Scenario B:** The second one calls `b()` prematurely and passes the return value from `b()` to your `.then()` handler.  `.then()` handlers expect function references to be passed to them, not promises so they don't use the promise you pass to them (they ignore it because it's not a function reference).  Remember `.then(b())` will execute `b()` first and then pass its return value to `.then()`.  That is clearly not what you want nor what `.then()` is designed to use.  See Promise specification detail below for more explanation of this.

**Scenario C:**  The third one correctly passes a function reference pointing to `b` to the `.then()` handler so it is the only one that properly chains the two promises.

---

**Promise Specification Explanation for Scenario B**

In your second case, you are passing a promise to a `.then()` handler as in `.then(somePromise)`.  The promise specification pretty clearly says that `.then()` must be passed something that is callable (which means a function reference).  When you don't pass a function reference, whatever you did pass will just be ignored and the previous resolved value (`aaa` in your case) will just be passed on down the chain.  Here's how the promise specification covers that:

In [25.4.5.3](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.prototype.then), there is the specification for `.then()`.
[image]

That ends up calling `PerformPromiseThen()` which is the next [section 25.4.5.3.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen)

[image]

That section explains that if the `onFulFilled` argument is not callable (e.g. not a function reference), then "Identify" is substituted.

Looking around further in the document, "Identity" is defined in [section 25.4.1.2](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promisereaction-records)

> The function that should be applied to the incoming value, and whose return value will govern what happens to the derived promise. If [[Handler]] is "Identity" it is equivalent to a function that simply returns its first argument.

This means that whatever was passed as the onFulFilled argument is ignored and an identity function (one that returns whatever first argument was passed to it).  In your case, the first argument is the resolved value of your first promise which is `aaa` so that's why that's what you see in the log for your second scenario.

Comment: So, if something that isn’t a function is passed to `then` (like `.then(b())`), it’s just _ignored_? It’s hard to find a reference to it, but I found [this in the ECMA-262 spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen): _“If `IsCallable(onFulfilled)` is `false`, then let `onFulfilled` be `"Identity"`.”_. Could you perhaps explain what this means or add a link?

Comment: @Xufox - "Identity" is described in 25.4.1.2 in that same document.  ***If [[Handler]] is "Identity" it is equivalent to a function that simply returns its first argument.***  What that practically means is that whatever non-callable thing was passed to the `.then()` handler is ignored and the substitute identify handler just returns the value it already had which in  your case is `aaa` which is what you log in your second case.

Comment: @Xufox - Added details from the specification to my answer to explain your second scenario where you're passing a promise to the `.then()` handler.

Comment: @user3701057 - If this answered your question, then please indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points.  If not, then please explain what part of your question is not yet answered.

Comment: @jfriend00, accepted the answer. Thank you for the detailed explanation.